# How to give unit tests access to Core Data models

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

Let's say I've made Core Data models in my project. I have other classes with methods that take in these models and perform some function based on their properties. How do I unit test those classes?

With normal Swift files I select them in Xcode and tick a box which makes any classes defined in those files visible to the unit test part of the project. My question is essentially, how do I make my Core Data models also visible to the tests?

Note that I don't want to perform any operations on the Core Data stack, I just want to be able to create an instance of a model and pass it into a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since CoreData uses Managed Objects, any subclass of NSManagedObject is functionally worthless unless attached to a context.

One trick for testing is to create an NSManagedObjectContext in memory and create objects test using that context. [Outlined Here](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/01/13/unit-testing-model-layer-core-data-swift/)

Here's the code for creating the context in memory:

```
func setUpInMemoryManagedObjectContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModelFromBundles([NSBundle.mainBundle()])!

    let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)

    do {
        try persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSInMemoryStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: nil, options: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Adding in-memory persistent store failed")
    }

    let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

    return managedObjectContext
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update: The accessor implementations are generated at runtime, but they are not usable if the model object is not associated with a `NSManagedObjectContext`. So PEEJWEEJ's answer is the way to go.**

If I am not mistaken, the Objective-C classes for your entities (in particular e.g. their property accessors) are generated at runtime, when they are used. So I would expect that you'd need to call `NSManagedObject`s initializer with the appropriate `NSEntityDescription`:

```
NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: nil)
```

You can get the appropriate entity descriptions by loading your object model with `NSManagedObjectModel` and using e.g. that object's `entitiesByName` property.

If you use custom code for your `NSManagedObject` subclasses (e.g. generated with [mogenerator](https://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator)), I would assume the same process would need to apply - make the generated code visible to your tests and use the `MyModelClass(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: nil)` initializer.

Comment: You Are mistaken :) You create the classes yourself (or generate them). The problem is that they're ManagedObjects, so the class' properties are not usable unless properly attached to the NSManagedObjectContext

Comment: What happens when using those properties outside a MOC?

Comment: The program will crash or throw an exception.