# Swift/OSX - How to give unit test Core Data access AND run the test without running the app

Tags: swift, macos, unit-testing, core-data

I'm using Core Data in my very small and simple app. It works fine. I'd like to set up some unit tests before I start growing the app and making it more complex. There are some hoops you have to jump through to get this to happen, but I've found [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25596702/swift-get-nsbundle-for-test-target) [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662947/unit-test-cant-find-core-data-model-file) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985415/how-to-give-unit-tests-access-to-core-data-models) on SE to get me through those hoops. The basic idea is that you have to create the object model manually. Easy enough; I adapted this code from one of the answers linked above, and problem solved.

```
let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.mergedModel(from: [Bundle.main])!
let persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
try! persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: nil, options: nil)

let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = persistentStoreCoordinator

NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "VAgentEditor", in: managedObjectContext)!
```

Great. But I also want to run my tests without running the app, just to test my low-level logic. More hoops to jump through. Lots of useful [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219706/xcode-5-unit-testing-starts-my-app) on this too, problem solved.

The trouble happens when I try to access Core Data **and** run without the app window. Naively combining the solutions to both problems, I get nil back from the call to `NSEntityDescription.entity()`. I've tweaked the above code in every way I can think of, but to no avail. If I can hack it enough get non-nil back from the call to `entity()`, I end up getting messages that `VAgentEditor` can't be found, or when I try to save the context to disk, I get a file that looks like something worked halfway --
lots of stuff in it, but no `VAgentEditor` like I get when I try only one of the two working scenarios described above.

When I try to point the unit test to the main app's bundle, I get various complaints about the bundle not being found, or the unit test not being able to use both its own bundle and the app bundle, and a hundred other complaints that I don't remember after hacking at this for a couple of days.

Is there a way to get my unit test to use CoreData, access the correct bundle to get at the classes I defined in Interface Builder, and run the test without running the main app?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is easier, if you use [CoreStore](https://github.com/JohnEstropia/CoreStore) for database handling. You set up your database with this code:

```
let dataStack: DataStack = {
    let dataStack = DataStack(xcodeModelName: "ModelName")
    do {
        try dataStack.addStorageAndWait()
    } catch let error {
        XCTFail("Cannot set up database storage: \(error)")
    }
    return dataStack
}()
```

Assuming that you have the following database object:

```
class User: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String

    func rename(name: String, transaction: BaseDataTransaction?) {
        guard let user = transaction.edit(self) else {
            return
        }
        user.name = name
    }

}
```

You can run a unit test like this:

```
class FileTests: XCTestCase {

    func testRename() {
        // 1. Arrange
        var user: User?
        do {
            try dataStack.perform(synchronous: { transaction in
                user = transaction.create(Into<User>())
                user!.name = "Test"
            })
        } catch let error {
            XCTFail("Cannot perform database transaction: \(error)")
        }

        // 2. Action
        do {
            try dataStack.perform(synchronous: { transaction in
            guard let user = transaction.edit(user!) else {
                return
            }
            user.rename(name: "Renamed", transaction: transaction)
            })
        } catch let error {
            XCTFail("Cannot perform database transaction: \(error)")
        }

        // 3. Assert
        do {
            try dataStack.perform(synchronous: { transaction in
            guard let user = transaction.edit(user!) else {
                return
            }
            XCTAssertEqual(user.name, "Renamed")
            })
        } catch let error {
            XCTFail("Cannot perform database transaction: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

This is just the beginning. You can streamline and improve the whole process but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks very much. A bit of a learning curve, but I got it to work in my tests without having to run the whole app. The in-code schema specification was key--it frees you from having to use the `.xcdatamodeld` file, so no ugly Bundle issues. Thanks.